# Abstracting selectors and action handlers from state

Tags: angular, ngxs

I was wondering whether it's possible to abstract the @Selectors and/or the @Action handlers from the @State class to a separate file? As the state grows bigger and as the selectors more complex, I'd like to move them to a separate file to keep the state class cleaner. Is there any way to do that in NGXS?

**Edit**: for future reference, I got an answer on the NGXS slack channel and it is indeed possible. We can create a separate selector class where to store all our selectors, passing them the state of interest as an argument.

```
export class EntityStateSelectors {
  @Selector([EntityState])
  thing(state: EntityStateModel) {
    return state.thing;
  }
}
```

As of now I still haven't figured out how to do the same for the action handlers, but extracting the selectors to a separate file already cleaned up the state class a lot !

Comment: Perhaps you need to have more states and/or child states?

Comment: Thanks for the input but that's not what I meant - I have a complex app structure already, with multiple child states. I also have quite a lot of selectors and action handlers, and to keep a clean app structure I wanted to split them to separate files (as in ngrx, which is the pattern I'm coming from). And it's possible! Check my updated question.

Comment: How do you handle creating circular references among parent->child relationships in this case?

Comment: @Ale I used the same pattern to separate selectors from action handlers but struggle to make it works with `angular9.1` + `ngxs3.6`. I have runtime errors at app init like `Cannot read property 'NGXS_SELECTOR_META' of undefined` where selector are used.. any hint on it?

Comment: @bertrandg Were you able to fix this `NGXS_SELECTOR_META`? I'm stuck with that error combining selectors of multiple states.

Comment: @CarlosEstebanLopezJaramillo yes, a bit tricky but it works now, check this github issue i did: https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1631

Comment: @bertrandg Thanks man, we already fixed it, had to refactor the data structure so the dependency was 1 way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a separate file for your selectors and is highly recommended. You can create a file like `app.selectors.ts` with something like this:

```js
export class AppSelectors {

  @Selector([AppState])
  static viewModel(state: AppStateModel) {
    // your selector logic here
  }

}
```

Then you can use normally in your components like this:

```js
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  @Select(AppSelectors.viewModel) vm$: Observable<ViewModel>;
}
```

This greatly reduces the size of your `app.state.ts` file since it leaves just the action handlers there. Also, this makes your code easier to test since your selectors are just pure functions

Comment: Yep, if you see I updated my question a while back with pretty much what you suggested here :)